# Запрос по API сохраняет в JSON файле слишком много информации

Tags: javascript, json, api

Запрос по API сохраняет в JSON файле слишком много информации, из этого мракобесия мне нужно только объект details и немного информции ниже

```
"details": [
        {
          "id": 80613219,
          "type": "phone",
          "data": "78223452354"
        }
      ],
      "created_at": "11.10.2023 12:10:26",
      "name": "Фёдор"
    }
```

```
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');

const url = 'https://direct.lptracker.ru/lead/77972070';
const token = 'kcsEkB2Nnjn6RnlEz3VFRfnN7te4DYwQ';

axios.get(url, { headers: { 'token': token } })
    .then(response => {
        const jsonData = JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2);

        fs.writeFile('result.json', jsonData, 'utf8', (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log('Результат сохранен в файл result.json');
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: `const {details} = response.data` Это если ключ `details` идет сразу за `response.data`.

Answer (score 0):

> Запрос по API сохраняет в JSON файле слишком много информации, из этого мракобесия мне нужно только объект details и немного информции ниже

Можно забрать нужные ключи и сделать JSON уже нужного объекта...

```js
const res = {
  "details": [
    {
      "id": 80613219,
      "type": "phone",
      "data": "78223452354"
    }
  ],
  "created_at": "11.10.2023 12:10:26",
  "name": "Фёдор",
  test1: 'некие данные 1',
  test2: 'некие данные 2',
  test3: 'некие данные 3',
  test4: 'некие данные 4',
}

const {details, created_at, name} = res
const str = JSON.stringify({details: details[0], created_at, name}, null, 2)
console.log(str)
```